# Is a bitmap required for drawing text on path in Android?

Tags: android, text, bitmap, path, draw

I created a function to **draw a text on a path**:

```
    public void drawText(float x, float y, String text) {
        Log.i("DRAWING", "drawText");Typeface.BOLD);
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mPath.lineTo(x+200,y);

        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
        textPaint.setTextSize(20f);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setStrokeWidth(5f);
        textPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mCanvas.drawTextOnPath(text, mPath, 0, 0, textPaint);
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
        paths.add(mPath);
        invalidate();
    }
```

I set a `Bitmap` like this:

```
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh)
    {
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        mCanvas = new Canvas();
        mCanvas.setBitmap(mBitmap);
        reset();
    }
```

## Question:

When I set a bitmap, it works fine and the text appears on the `ImageView`, but when I don't, just a white line appears and not the text.
Do I have to use a `Bitmap` to draw text on path with `drawTextOnPath` ? Because I want to use only paths (all works fine except text, like it needed a `Bitmap`).

Comment: It seems that your question already includes its answer... `When I set a bitmap, it works fine and the text appears on the ImageView, but when I don't, just a white line appears and not the text. Do I have to use a Bitmap to draw text on path with drawTextOnPath ?`

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Ok, then why the text is not appearing when I don't use Bitmap ?

Comment: An ImageView is a Bitmap container. You must feed it with a Bitmap.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein So you are saying that a Bitmap is mandatory to draw text but not to draw paths ? And so, it's not possible to store text in paths ?

Comment: `store text in paths` **?** Do you mean to make a path which follows the text outline? Maybe, But it would be an overkill. What do you have against a Bitmap?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I implemented a Undo/Redo functionnality so I didn't want to save both Bitmaps and Paths. But I guess I have no choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So a `Bitmap` is **mandatory** to draw text with `drawTextOnPath`.

The text won't appear if there is no `Bitmap`.

For those who, like me, implemented a *Undo/Redo functionnality*, I guess you have to **save both paths and bitmaps** to allow user to go back and forward.